# Delphi SQL subselect error in MS-Access

Tags: delphi, ms-access, ado

I'm using Delphi 7 with ADO components, and MS Access 2003. The SQL sentence

```
SELECT CMCB.Name, 
     (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM movement MCB
     WHERE MCB.movement_classification_id=CMCB.movement_classification_id
     AND MCB.operation_date >= #01/01/2013#
     AND MCB.operation_date < #01/01/2014#
 ) AS MyYear 
 FROM movement_classification CMCB
```

is working fine in MS Access console but through a Delphi application launches the following error when I am opening the DataSet (**TADOQuery**):

**Data provider or other service returned an E_FAIL status**

Any idea why it happens? Is it related with the ADO component (TADOQuery in this case)

I tried a similar query from the database **dbdemos.mdb** (Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\Data) and it works

```
SELECT CustNo, 
    (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM orders O 
    WHERE O.CustNo = C.CustNo 
    AND O.SaleDate >= #01/01/1994# 
    AND O.SaleDate < #01/01/1995#
) AS AmountPaid 
FROM customer C
```

The code I used in Delphi is the following:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    ADOConnection1.Connected := False;
    ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=D:\Xiber\Delphi\StackOverflow\Subquerys\dbdemos.mdb';
    ADOConnection1.Connected := True;

    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'SELECT CustNo, (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM orders O WHERE O.CustNo = C.CustNo AND O.SaleDate >= #01/01/1994# AND O.SaleDate < #01/01/1995#) AS AmountPaid FROM customer C';
    ADOQuery1.Open;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
    sSQL: string;
begin
    ADOConnection1.Connected := False;
    ADOConnection1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;User ID=Admin;Data Source=D:\Xiber\Delphi\StackOverflow\Subquerys\XiGest-CASA.mdb';
    ADOConnection1.Connected := True;

    sSQL := ' SELECT CMCB.Name, ' +
        ' (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM movement MCB ' +
        ' WHERE MCB.movement_classification_id=CMCB.movement_classification_id ' +
        ' AND MCB.operation_date >= #01/01/2013# ' +
        ' AND MCB.operation_date < #01/01/2014# ' +
        ' ) AS MyYear ' +
        ' FROM movement_classification CMCB ';
    ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := sSQL;
    ADOQuery1.Open;
end;
```

Comment: I don't think there's enough information here to find out what is wrong. Is there no error code, no other detailed message, nothing?

Comment: This is a bit of a strange subquery, with no relations between the tables at all. What happens if you use a subquery like e.g. these http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html?

Comment: Does MS Access support Common Table Expressions? If so use it

Comment: What happens if you alias the column the subselect generates?

Comment: 2 things here, first this query will show the same qty for every name, is that really what u are after ?  Second, where do u get this error in delphi ? On opening the query or where ? Do other queries work or is it just this one that gives an error ? Need some more info before able to help here

Comment: Sorry guys. I oversimplyfied the question. This is my first time. I am gonna rebuild the question, but I am not interested in the meaning of the query, it works for me. Just I can not open the query in Delphi 7 using ADO components

Comment: E_FAIL is a very generic ADO error message. Two things you might check. 1) are there null values in the operation_date column and 2) is there a semicolon at the end of your sql text in the ADO SQL property (if you copied the query text from Access and pasted into Delphi, there will be a semicolon)?

Comment: @SamM Thanks Sam, those weren't my cases. I had tried to remove the NULL fileds before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I realised the difference between the two sums was that in dbdemos the field AmountPaid.mdb is **double** and in my case is **decimal(8,2)**.

It seems to be an **ADO bug**. You can reproduce by yourself.

So, If you change the field AmountPaid in **dbdemos.mdb** (provided by Borland, you can found at Program Files\Common Files\Borland Shared\Data) to decimal(8,2) and execute the query through Delphi 7 (with an **ADOConnection** and an **ADOQuery**), you'll get the error above mentioned.

```
SELECT CustNo, 
    (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM orders O 
    WHERE O.CustNo = C.CustNo 
    AND O.SaleDate >= #01/01/1994# 
    AND O.SaleDate < #01/01/1995#
) AS AmountPaid 
FROM customer C
```

But if you execute this query inside MS Access, it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands, your query should return the same value for sum(qty) for each row of employee. If Access is "hiding" the relationship between the two tables, that could explain why it works in Access.
I would expect a query something like:

```
    select e.name, sum(i.qty)
    from
        employee e,
        items i
    where
        i.employeeid = e.employeeid
```

would be something more like what you're after. This, of course, assumes a direct relationship (the foreign key of employeeid in the items table) between the two tables, which is not very realistic.

As others have commented, more information would permit a more precise answer!

Is there any reason you couldn't simplify the query (assuming it is an ADO bug) such as:

```
    select CMCB.Name, SUM(MCB.amount)
    from
        movement_classification CMCB,
        movement MCB
    where
        MCB.movement_classification_id=CMCB.movement_classification_id
        AND MCB.operation_date >= #01/01/2013#
        AND MCB.operation_date < #01/01/2014#
```

Comment: Okay, jciberta, that looks a lot better! After you set ADOConnection1.Connected to true, have you tested that Connected is actually true? If it isn't, that would imply a problem in your connection string.

Comment: Yes, ADOConnection1.Connected is set to true. Moreover, I deleted all the tables in the database and several fields in the two tables, and I reduced the size to 1.608 KB. The error still persists

Comment: I'm sorry I don't have MS-Access so I can't check for myself, but is it possible the character sets of the two databases are different? It could also be an ADO bug. Check my answer for a variation to your query.

Comment: Thanks Pat, but I found finally the bug. Sorry again for the query. It is still simplified, so there was no need to change it. The real query is with more subselects in the select statement, indeed, one per month. Something like SELECT (SELECT ...) AS January, ..., (SELECT ...) AS December ...